# What version of ruby and ruby on rails is supported by aptana studio 3 - including the debugging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

There are many version of ruby.
I know that the versions I have (ruby 2.1.2p95) won't work because it apparently doesn't have a functioning ruby-debug-ide.
I'm using Rails 4.1.4

I have just installed Aptana Studio 3 (Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2.201308081805)
After trying debug run of the program in Aptana , I was informed that the rdebug wasn't available.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

I looking for specific ruby/ruby on rails versions that have proved to be reliable with the Aptana Studio 3 debugging environment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Marc

Comment: Do you _have_ to use Aptana rather than--for example--RubyMine?

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.0.0p247. Haven't upgraded in a while. It works with rails 4. The newest versions of ruby and rails often tend to break things because its such a fast moving platform